# Executing update in MERGE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Command in C# that works to merge data from one table to another.

The difficulties I have are when I try to update rows, instead of add new ones.

my C# SQL that works:

```
string sql = $@"MERGE my_table as target
                USING ( SELECT @name, @id, @date, @task, @status )
                AS source ( [Username], [User_ID], [Task_Date], [Task_Type], [Task_Status] )
                ON ( target.User_ID = source.User_ID AND target.Task_Date = source.Task_Date )
                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                INSERT ( [Username], [User_ID], [Task_Date], [Task_Type], [Task_Status] )
                VALUES ( @name, @id, @date, @task, @status );";
```

when I try to update the task status, I get an exception, invalid syntax near my_table. I have both tried using my_table.Task_Status and target.Task_Status and I get the same exception

```
string sql = $@"MERGE my_table as target
                USING ( SELECT @name, @id, @date, @task, @status )
                AS source ( [Username], [User_ID], [Task_Date], [Task_Type], [Task_Status] )
                ON ( target.User_ID = source.User_ID AND target.Task_Date = source.Task_Date )
                WHEN MATCHED THEN
                UPDATE my_table SET my_table.Task_Status = @status
                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                INSERT ( [Username], [User_ID], [Task_Date], [Task_Type], [Task_Status] )
                VALUES ( @name, @id, @date, @task, @status );";
```

the rest of the c# if needed:

```
// Assume the record below is already in the database
// string[] record_in_db = {"Joe","123","5/12/2021","Stack Question","In Progress"}
// I want to update the record with the information below, 
// Change task status from in progress to completed with my UPDATE in the MERGE statement
string[] value = {"Joe","123","5/12/2021","Stack Question","Completed"}
string sql_con = "server = ; Database = ; User ID = ; Password  = ;";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sql_con))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    // Add Parameters to SQL Query
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", value[0]);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", value[1]);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", value[2]);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@task", value[3]);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", value[4]);
    try
    {
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that just be `UPDATE SET target.Task_Status = @status`

Comment: @juharr this is the correct answer

Comment: @juharr , i just checked and there were no syntax errors and the data record does exist as an updated task. I tried both `target` and `my_table`, but the thing that screwed me up when I tried both was I had `UPDATE my_table SET`, which was probably causing the sytnax error. So when I changed to `UPDATE SET target.Task_Status = @status` everything compiled. Thanks

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: By the way a little tip: I always declare my SQL strings `const string` to ensure there is no chance of trying to inject data into the query

Comment: @Charlieface not sure that's useful advice at all, its simply a distraction to this post. `const` wont affect the chances of injection of this type of parameterised query, you might declare them const for other management reasons, but here unless the code base is compromised and recompiled, that type of injection is not on the radar.